# ubuntu server downloading dropbox directory

Tags: server, dropbox

how would i download a dropbox folder without downloading dropbox to my ubuntu server? Cause dropbox can send links but i cant figure out how to download it as a zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's a public link that renders in your browser instead of downloading.  Dropbox site [suggests](https://www.dropbox.com/help/201) to add "?dl=1" to the end of the url.